# Place controls on a movable and zoomable form in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I want to place some xaml controls in a dragable (pressed ctrl and use mouse) and zoomable canvas in WPF. What is the best thing to place my controls on? The controls should not be moved or resized, i just want to zoom in and out and drag the hole ui around, like in kxaml or the visual studio ui designer.

What is the best starting point? Using a canvas or are flow documents made for this purpose? Hope my question is clear formulated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: for example - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97871/WPF-simple-zoom-and-drag-support-in-a-ScrollViewer

Comment: Drag also can be done with TranslateTransform, but, as for me, MouseMove is better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `ScrollViewer` in combination with a `Canvas` fromt he CodeProject article did the trick. For more information see the comment from @Spawn.